# Core Animations with AVAssetWriter possible?

Tags: ios, core-animation, avassetwriter

I know about the `AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool` method to use Core animations and I made it work using `AVMutableComposition`, but I'm looking for a way to do the same animations through `AVAssetWriter`. Basically I want to create `CAAnimation`(s) and use the `AVAssetWriter`'s buffer timestamp as the animation timing method. Then pull the animated properties for each frame.

Is this possible at all? Any guide to the proper direction will be appreciated.

Edit: If you're wondering why not just use `AVAssetExportSession` instead, it's because my requirements prevent me from using the compression presets, plus I need to use `CIFilter`s which cannot be used currently with `CALayer`s on iOS.

Comment: Have you got any solution for this? I am facing similar situation. If yes please help.

Comment: Did you find a solution?